# Back-end solution for pure-Javascript site with link sharing

Tags: javascript, firebase, backend

I'm developer-beginner and I would like to do simple **card-sorting site**.

- hundreds of cards with plain text
- no log-ins, it must be as simple for user as possible
- few dozens users per day
- final state of sorting should be saved under unique link, like site.com/q56we1cfuz4 or site.com/link.php?unique=q56we1cfuz4

User sorts cards as he/she wishes and the result is saved into browser sessions storage (few kb of data in JSON or so). So far, so good.

**Question:**

As I know only Javascript:

1. If I need to **share the state of the page** (data in session storage) with some unique link, is something like Firebase.com good solution for such kind of back-end? Or some simple DB with help od Node.js?
2. In order to "catch" the link when someone click at unique URL (site.com/link.php?unique=q56we1cfuz4), **I still need some server-side script** which will ask the DB, like PHP header redirect, right?

Comment: *"is something like Firebase.com good solution for such kind of back-end"* is asking for *opinion*, which is off-topic for SO. Also, ask **one** question per question, not two.

Comment: Re "server side script" - You can use JavaScript server-side as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions are a little fuzzy, no problem tho.  You are just getting into web dev, so there's a lot to wrap your head around and all of the options can be pretty confusing.  Some people will complain about opinionated answers, and I'm not going to claim to be objective here, but here are a few tips that I think will get you pointed in a better direction...

Firstly, yes - firebase is a good solution for you to try working with.  Aside from the fact that it will give you the db/storage features you need, it's a realtime db, which will give you a lot more than just storage in the long run, and will better equip you for the future web development trends.  The firebase API is (mostly) designed to work asynchronously, so from a javascript perspective, it falls right in line with the kind of code you'll end up learning to write.

Re: the other aspect of your question - server-side - check out nodeJS.  It's basically a server-side javascript platform that will allow you to use the same skills you're learning to write client-side code for the server.  Also check out expressJS, a nodeJS package that provides you the http-server, and allows you to handle dynamic urls, etc. - the bits you were thinking about when you made a reference to PHP.

Hopefully this will help you focus on a few specific tools to familiarize yourself with as you learn web development, rather than having to struggle with everything from new languages, platforms, and way too many libraries, frameworks and techniques to wrap your head around.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help!